# JDBC query fails, though it runs from pgAdmin

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm having a weird issue. I have an update query in my code, which i'm running from a Java app.
I have a PreparedStatement, for which i pass on 2 java.sql.Date parameters. When i run the query, it logs this exception:

```
DatabaseObject - Failed to execute update query: UPDATE data_cache_cycle_data dc SET last_7days_receipts = sq.x  FROM  (SELECT asin,count(asin) as x     FROM  inventory     WHERE  created_date = (date '2012-08-22 +02:00:00' - '6 day'::interval)     GROUP BY asin ) AS sq     WHERE  dc.asin = sq.asin .

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"

Position: 177

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2101)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1834)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:510)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:332)
```

Now, if i copy paste the query from the exception log, the query executes without a problem in pgAdmin.

What am i missing?

Comment: I think i can solve this by calculating the 6 days previous date in java and passing that to the query. SO i think the "created_date >= (date '2012-08-22 +02:00:00' - '6 day'::interval) " part is failing, just cannot see how and why.

Comment: are you using a prepared statement and placeholders? if so, how is it structured, i.e. are you saying `?::interval` in the query text?

Comment: Please show the JDBC code and the raw query text you sent to PgJDBC.

Comment: query =  "UPDATE data_cache_cycle_data dc SET last_7days_receipts = sq.x " +
            " FROM  (SELECT asin,count(asin) as x " +
            "    FROM  inventory " +
            "    WHERE  created_date <= ? AND created_date >= (date ? - '6 day'::interval) " + //6 days, because we run this app over the evening
            "    GROUP BY asin ) AS sq " +
            "    WHERE  dc.asin = sq.asin ";

This query is used for a plain PreparedStatement and the two parameters are the instances of a java.sql.Date object. Plain JDBC, no trickery.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **'6 day'::interval**, but a proper CAST(): **CAST('6 day' AS interval)**

Answer (score 0):

':' in jdbc is a placeholder for named parameters.
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html

 You may have to find a way to escape it.
In hibernate we use backslash '\' to escape ':'. If it does not work find a way to escape it because there surely ought to be a way to do that.